# Stoppable Thread Error

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am creating a stoppable thread class :

```
import threading

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()
```

However when I create the object like so :

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myFile.py", line 81, in <module>
    aObject = StoppableThread(target, args=("foo", "bar",)))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overridden **init** method and you don't have "args" argument there.

You have to do something like:

```
 def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self._stop = threading.Event()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `__init__` does not take any arguments. You want your `__init__` function to accept *any* positional arguments and any keyword arguments which `Thread.__init__` accepts. You want to pass all of them to the base implmentation:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StoppableThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # ...
```

See also: [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)